# How do you let all the sub pages to the main page?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do you let all the sub pages to the main page?

sampel.com/2/sampel.html

so

sampel.com/sampel.html

so all sub pages move to the main page

wear .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `How do you let all the sub pages to the main page?`

Here is you do that via mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.html)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /pages/head.php?cari=$1 [L,NC]
```

This will redirect every `/dir/file.html` to `/file.html`

Comment: I have the code: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /pages/head.php?cari=$1 [L] . when I run your code, it did not take him to the main page, but out 404.php . whether the code clash?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [search for examples](https://www.google.nl/search?q=mod_rewrite+examples+htaccess).

I am not sure if you want to have an external redirect, or an internal rewrite. For the rule I show below, I am assuming you want the url in the browser to change, and therefore want an external redirect. First you need to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache install. Then enable the rewriteengine in your .htaccess file and write the rules below it. You'll need to use "RewriteRule". The first argument is a regex that matches the request. The second argument is what it is rewritten to. The third arguments are a list of flags. You can find information about them in the documentation linked above. You want to make sure the first argument doesn't match the part that it is rewritten to, or you'll create an infinite loop, eventually causing an error somewhere. The following rule should do what you want it to do.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^2/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: if using for all the page numbers, how? because i try, edit 2 to ([0-9]+) it does not work, they took it to sampel.com/pages